# Trying to Run this Mips Assembly program on QT Spim

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I have to make a program in MIPs Assembly to match this C program:

```
int count(int a[], int n, int x)
{
int res = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int loc[];
for(i = 0; i != n; i++)
if(a[i] == x) {
res = res + 1;
loc [j] = i;
j = j+1}
return res, loc;
}
```

Plus these requirements:

· Hard-code the following values into array a:
128, 10, 23, 12, 128, 9, 220, 46, 128, 5, 12, 23, 46, 5, 10, 10, 45, 24, 31, 67, 12, 128, 45, 32, 67, 12, 220,
9, 128, 46

· Hard-code n = 16

· Prompt the user to enter 3 values as follows: “Please enter the three integer values to find.”

· Read the integer values and store them (lets call them x, y, z)

· Call the function count with the following arguments: count(a, 16, (x,y,z))

· Output the results as follows: “The number of times x/y/z appears in the list 
is res times and is located in
position/s loc” (do the same for the 3 numbers that you are looking for).

· Exit the program

So I have made this program, but when I run it in QT Spim it says:

Memory and registers cleared

Loaded: C:/Users/100520384/AppData/Local/Temp/QtSpim.Hp8592

Which means it's not running, someone please tell me why :(

```
.data
Prompt: .asciiz  "Please enter an integer: "                #Prompt for the user
Msg1:       .asciiz  "\nThe number of times "               #Three parts for the ending message
Msg2:       .asciiz  " appears in the list "                        #to put all of the variables in the middle
Msg3:       .asciiz  " times and is located in position "

inputNum:   .space 4            #space to store the inputed Number

n:              .word 16            #n = 16
loc:            .word  0:30     #up to 30 elements
A:              .word  128, 10, 23, 12, 128, 9, 220, 46, 128, 5, 12, 23, 46, 5, 10, 10, 45, 24, 31, 67, 12, 128, 45, 32, 67, 12, 220, 9, 128, 46
                                    #A has 30 hard coded values
.text

input:
#input and output 
li          $v0, 4              #load system call for print (4)
la      $a0, Prompt     #load the adress of "Prompt" to $a0
syscall                         #call the system to print Prompt

li          $v0, 5              #load system call for input(5)
syscall                         #call the system to take input
move    $t0, $v0                #store the inputed integer in $t0


check:
li          $t7, 0              #variable for checking if we have 3 integers being checked
li          $s2, 3              #maxmium amount to integers inputed     

count:
la          $s0, A              #$s0 is initiated to the first element of A
la          $s1, loc            #$s1 is intiated to the first element of loc
la          $t3, n              #$t3 is n

li          $t4, 0              #int i
li          $t5, 0              #int j
li          $t6, 0              #int res
j       loop

loop:
beq     $t4, $t3, endCount          #for loop check if ( i != n )
beq     $s0, $t0, yep                   #if (a[ i ] = x)
j       loop    

yep:
addi        $t6, $t6, 1         #increment res

sw      $t4, ($s1)          #set loc[ j ] to i
addi        $t3, $t3, 1         #increment j
addi        $t4, $t4, 1         #increment i

addi        $s1, $s1, 4     #set the next element for loc
addi        $s0, $s0, 4     #set the next element for A
j       loop

endCount:
addi        $t7, $t7, 1         #increment the check variable 

li          $v0, 4              #load system call for printing strings(4)
la          $a0, Msg1           #print first part of message
syscall

li          $v0, 1              #load system call for printing integers(1)
move    $a0, $t0
syscall

li          $v0, 4              #load system call for printing strings(4)
la          $a0, Msg2           #print second part of message
syscall

li          $v0, 1              #load system call for printing integers(1)
move    $a0, $t6            #print res
syscall

li          $v0, 4              #load system call for printing strings(4)
la          $a0, Msg3           #print third part of message
syscall

li          $v0, 1              #load system call for printing integers(1)
move    $a0, $s1            #print loc position
syscall

blt     $t7, $s2,  input    #if three integers have not been inputed loop

li          $v0, 10             # give the system call code to exit the program
syscall                         # execute system call
```

Comment: qtspim is a simulator, single step it.

Comment: Do you mean only use one sub-routine?

Comment: No, I mean, let it execute the instructions one by one so you can see where your problem is. Note you don't seem to have an entry point `main` at all, so maybe fix that first.